# INNER JOIN two table get error SQL Statment not ended properly

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two table which I want to select `Name` from t2. 
The situation is following. 
I have t1 `Policy` which containt `EmployeeID`
And table `t2` which containt `Name`
Now I want to select which Employee release policy.
So in t1(Policy- AUTO.POL) I have column: SIFRA_RAD
and t2(Employee-AUTO.SIFRAD) I have colum: SIFRA_R, Ime

I try something like this:

```
select auto.pol.sifra_rad, auto.sifrad.ime
from auto.sifrad 
inner join auto.pol on  auto.sifrad.ime = auto.pol.sifra_rad;
```

After that I get error

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

I have no idea what is wrong here. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from query, and we fix it

```
select p.sifra_rad, s.ime from auto.sifrad s, auto.pol p where s.ime = p.sifra_rad
```